# F# get set of subsets containing k elements

Tags: f#

Given a set with `n` elements `{1, 2, 3, ..., n}`, I want to declare a function which returns the set containing the sets with `k` number of elements such as:

```
allSubsets 3 2
```

Would return `[[1;2];[1;3];[2;3]]` since those are the sets with `2` elements in a set created by `1 .. n`

I've made the initial create-a-set-part but I'm a little stuck on how to find out all the subsets with `k` elements in it.

```
let allSubsets n k =
    Set.ofList [1..n] |>
```

UPDATE:

I managed to get a working solution using yield:

```
let allSubsets n k =
let setN = Set.ofList [1..n] 
let rec subsets s = 
    set [ 
        if Set.count s = k then yield s
        for e in s do
            yield! subsets (Set.remove e s) ]
subsets setN

allSubsets 3 2
val it : Set<Set<int>> = set [set [1; 2]; set [1; 3]; set [2; 3]]
```

But isn't it possible to do it a little cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is pretty clean, but it's also pretty inefficient. Try running `allSubsets 10 3` and you'll know what I mean.

This is what I came up with:

```
let input = Set.ofList [ 1 .. 15 ]

let subsets (size:int) (input: Set<'a>) = 
    let rec inner elems = 
        match elems with
        | [] -> [[]]
        | h::t -> 
            List.fold (fun acc e -> 
                if List.length e < size then 
                    (h::e)::e::acc 
                else e::acc) [] (inner t)
    inner (Set.toList input)
    |> Seq.choose (fun subset ->
        if List.length subset = size then
            Some <| Set.ofList subset
        else None)
    |> Set.ofSeq

subsets 3 input
```

The `inner` recursive function is a modified power set function from [here](http://www.fssnip.net/4b/title/Powerset). My first hunch was to generate the power set and then filter it, which would be pretty elegant, but that proved to be rather inefficient as well.

If this was to be production-quality code, I'd look into generating lists of indices of a given length, and use them to index into the input array. This is how FsCheck generates subsets, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the powerset and then filter in order to get only the ones with the specified length":

```
let powerset n k =
    let lst = Set.toList n     
    seq [0..(lst.Length |> pown 2)-1] 
        |> Seq.map (fun i -> 
            set ([0..lst.Length-1] |> Seq.choose (fun x -> 
                if i &&& (pown 2 x) = 0 then None else Some lst.[x])))
    |> Seq.filter (Seq.length >> (=) k)
```

However this is not efficient for large sets (n) of where k is close to n. But it's easy to optimize, you'll have to filter out early based on the digit count of the binary representation of each number.

Answer (score 0):

This function implements the popular n-choose-k function:

```
let n_choose_k (arr: 'a []) (k: int) : 'a list list =
    let len = Array.length arr
    let rec choose lo x =
        match x with
        | 0 -> [[]]
        | i -> [ for j in lo..(len-1) do
                   for ks in choose (j+1) (i-1) do
                       yield arr.[j]::ks ]
    choose 0 k

> n_choose_k [|1..3|] 2;;
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [1; 3]; [2; 3]]
```

You can use Set.toArray and Set.ofList to convert to and from Set.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach:

1. get powerset

```cs
    let rec powerset xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> [ [] ]
    | h :: t -> List.fold (fun ys s -> (h :: s) :: s :: ys) [] (powerset t)
```

2. filter all subsets with a neccessary number of elements

```cs
    let filtered xs k = List.filter (fun (x: 'a list) -> x.Length = k) xs
```

3. finally get the requested allSubsets

```cs
    let allSubsets n k = Set.ofList (List.map (fun xs -> Set.ofList xs) (filtered (powerset [ 1 .. n ]) k))
```

Just to check and play with you can use:

```cs
    printfn "%A" (allSubsets 3 2) // set [ set [1; 2]; set [1; 3]; set [2; 3] ]
```